# Hadoop Datanode fails with Return value 3 (Kerberos enabled)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, mit-kerberos

[image: Picture showing datanode not running and datanode was stopped when initiating start]

I have enabled Kerberos for the Datanode.

When i try to start the datanode. It fails with the return value 3.

But, user Login  from the keytab file was perfect. Datanode communication with namenode was also happening.

Also ps aux shows the datanode daemon running.

Any suggestions/answer for this weird behavior.

Note: This is a single node cluster and Namenode is running. No problem with the Keytab file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem with init script.
It checks wrong pid file.
Secured hadoop use /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop_secure_dn.pid
But script still checks /var/run/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode.pid
So error message can be fixed by changing PIDFILE varaible:

```
PIDFILE="/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop_secure_dn.pid"
```

in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode